# Compute Distribution of Linear Function

Tags: probability

Let  $Y = aX + b + \varepsilon $ , $X \sim \exp (\theta )$ , $\varepsilon  \sim N(0,{\sigma ^2})$ ,

$X$ and $\varepsilon $ are independent

How we can find distribution of $Y$?

Thank you.

Comment: I would look at the characteristic function of $Y$. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution.

Comment: Use _convolution_ of the densities.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a\geq 0$ we have $aX\sim\exp(a\theta)$ and $b+\varepsilon\sim N(b,\sigma^2)$, hence the pdf of $Y$ is given by:
$$f(t)=\frac{a\theta}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-a\theta z}e^{-\frac{(t-z-b)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\, dz.$$